# How to disable system sound effect on AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, audio

I have an AlertDialog with 2 buttons. I want them to play my custom sound when they're clicked. So I have this code on every button:

```
SoundUtility.getInstance(Add_Edit_Note.this).playPositive();
```

SoundUtility is a class I wrote to play custom sounds.
Here's the problem: it does play my custom sound, but simultaneously it also plays the system sound effect, so I have two sounds playing at the same time. I was able to disable it on the regular buttons by rewriting the Button:

```
public class AppButton extends Button {

public AppButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // Disable sound effect
    this.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
}

}
```

and then in my XML file:

```
<com.my.app.AppButton
    ... />
```

but I can't find a way to disable these system sound effects on AlertDialog buttons. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

As requested, this is the SoundUtility code:

```
public class SoundUtility {
private static SoundUtility soundInstance;
private MediaPlayer mpPositive;
private MediaPlayer mpNegative;

public static SoundUtility getInstance(Context context){

    if(soundInstance==null)
    {
        soundInstance = new SoundUtility(context);
    }

    return soundInstance;
}

private SoundUtility (Context context)
{
    mpPositive = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.click_positive);
    mpNegative = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.click_negative);
}

// Playing positive sound
public void playPositive() {
    mpPositive.start();
}

// Playing negative sound
public void playNegative() {
    mpNegative.start();
}

// Releasing MediaPlayer
public void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    mpPositive.release();
    mpNegative.release();
}
```

}

**EDIT 2**

The code of my AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel?")
        .setCancelable(false) // The dialog is modal, a user must provide an answer
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // If the answer is Yes
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                ...
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED); // Setting result as cancelled and returning it to main activity
                SoundUtility.getInstance(Add_Edit_Note.this).playPositive(); // Play positive sound
                Add_Edit_Note.this.finish(); // Closing current activity
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // If the answer is No
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                SoundUtility.getInstance(Add_Edit_Note.this).playNegative(); // Play negative sound
                dialog.cancel(); // Closing the confirmation dialog
            }
        });
builder.create().show(); // Present the dialog to the user
```

Comment: I think you should post the code for your SoundUtility class, it must be playing this system sound effect in there somewhere.

Comment: @breadbin Posted the SoundUtility code. But really there's nothing in there that plays that system sound effect, only my custom sounds...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
Button btn = dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE); 
btn.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

Call `setSoundEffectsEnabled` for all the buttons that you have

**EDIT:**

Instead of

```
 builder.create().show();
```

use

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();

Button btn = dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE); 
btn.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);

Button btn2 = dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE); 
btn2.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Where exactly should I place this code? I tried it inside the onClick method of the Dialog, but I got an error, saying "The method getButton(int) is undefined for the type DialogInterface". I tried to cast 'dialog' to '((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton', it got rid of the error message, but I still had that system sound effect.

Comment: place it after you create the dialog and just before show. Also do post the code where you are creating the dialog, you should change BUTTON_POSITIVE to whatever type of buttons you are using

Comment: Still no luck... I updated the question with my AlertDialog code, where do I put this code in there?

Comment: Tried it, first I got this error for the getButton method: `The method getButton(int) is undefined for the type Dialog`. It suggested to add cast, I did, it removed the error but then the app crashed.

Comment: change Dialog to AlertDialog like I have done, also do post the crash log

Comment: I tried to change Dialog to AlertDialog, the app still crashes. The log says there's this problem: `at com.my.app.Add_Edit_Note.onClick(Add_Edit_Note.java:272)` and this line is `btn.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);`

Comment: Here's the log file (I can't post the entire log here): [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30043022/log.txt)

Comment: I posted the updated answer, looks like creation of dialog is done after show and not when create is done

Comment: Thank you so very much! Finally no system sound effects! Such a relief! :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to turn off sound feedback globally by putting **`android:soundEffectsEnabled=false`** in a theme.

**You can apply the theme to the entire application from the manifest file.**

**Alternative Way :**

You can create one class and use it in layout files...

your Class :

```
package com.me.customeapp

public class MeTextView extends TextView {

    public MeTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Inside your xml file put below code:

```
<com.me.customeapp.TextView
...  
</com.me.customeapp.TextView>
```

try it out. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I never used theme files... Where do I locate it?

Comment: You can apply the theme to the entire application from the manifest file

Comment: I have Updated my post. you can review it

Comment: I think I do have a theme applied to my application in the manifest: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="MyAppName"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >... But I have no idea where to insert this line `android:soundEffectsEnabled=false`. I tried in several places (the manifest itself, AppTheme file...), but ran into error messages.